# Rendering on a 48 bit rgb image using OpenGl

Tags: image, opengl, direct2d

I have a 16 bit gray scale image with me and I want to draw annotations on top of that.
Initially i started with Direct 2d and later I realized that it is not possible to render 16 bit/channel in direct 2d

Later i moved to Open Gl and now I am not able to conclude that will Open gl support rendering in 16 bit/channel image.I have studied about frame buffer object.and also about mesa3d library

Answer (score 1):

Yes, render targets with 16 bits per component are supported in OpenGL. The following is from the OpenGL 3.3 spec, which is the latest version that supports DX10 level hardware.

You can find the spec documents by going to www.opengl.org, and clicking at the "OpenGL Registry" entry in the "Documentation" menu close to the top left corner. This leads you to https://www.opengl.org/registry. On that page, you can view/download all spec documents in PDF format.

In the 3.3 spec, the critical information is under *Required Texture Formats* on pages 142/143 in section 3.9 (*Texturing*). In the list for *Texture and renderbuffer color formats* (where "renderbuffer" means that the format can be rendered to), you will find among others:

- RGBA16
- RG16
- R16

These are 16 bit/component formats with 4, 2, and 1 component.

*Texture-only color formats* just below this includes:

- RGB16

This is he 16 bit/component format with 3 components.

So the exact 48-bit RGB format you were asking about turns out to **not** be valid as a render target. But at the price of using more memory, the 64-bit RGBA format should work just fine.

Comment: So what should be the basic workflow.I have raw 16 bit grayscale image with me..I first create a frame buffer .and fill it up with grayscale image.making a 64 bit render target by copying same pixel value in r g abd b and setting alpha value to 1.then?

Comment: @user3845376: Framebuffers are where you're drawing to. Your image goes into a 16 bit per channel **texture**. Then you draw triangles and fetch from the texture in the fragment shader. To avoid image filtering when using a 1:1 zoom level use the `texelFetch` function. For other zoom levels use the regular `texture` GLSL texture access function.

Comment: Thank you datenwolf it really helped i have started using OpenGl yesterday only.do you know any other library using which i can use to draw on 16 bit grayscale image.